# How do I install jtransc?

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

The [jtransc](https://github.com/jtransc/jtransc) Github README shows there is a gradle plugin I can add with:

```
plugins {
    id "com.jtransc" version "0.6.8"
}
```

But whenever I sync the project it shows the following error:

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.jtransc:jtransc-main:unspecified.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/jtransc/jtransc-main/unspecified/jtransc-main-unspecified.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/jtransc/jtransc-main/unspecified/jtransc-main-unspecified.jar
     Required by:
         project : > com.jtransc:com.jtransc.gradle.plugin:0.6.8 > gradle.plugin.com.jtransc:jtransc-gradle-plugin:0.6.8
```

and if I go to those URLs in my browser, it returns a 404.

How can I get the jtransc gradle plugin to work in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why `plugins` block doesn't work, but the following does the job:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.jtransc:jtransc-gradle-plugin:0.6.8"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.jtransc"
```

Maybe it's published incorrectly because this `gradle.plugin.` prefix [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jtransc) seems totally out of place.

Comment: Important Note: only works with gradle 4 or gradle 5 -- don't try with gradle 6